# Adding extenal library to compiler toolchain for ARM

Tags: linux, gnu-toolchain, arm7

I have downloaded compiler tool chain for ARM Target.

My host machine: Linux
Target H/w : ARM7

But i need to add some additional library with that tool chain.

I need to know how to add new library to existing tool chain?

Thanks 
Hari